# Renormalizing a probability matrix in a guessing game

Tags: probability, distributions, normalization

I have a game that's finding the correct one-to-one mapping between members of one group $A$ to members of another group $B$.

I have chosen to represent the mapping probabilities as a matrix $P$ of size $M x M$. Each position $P_{ij}$ corresponds to the probability that $A_i$ maps to $B_j$.

Each turn I'm allowed to ask whether $A_i$ maps to $B_j$ and am given a definitive answer, yes or no. If the answer is yes, then I can set $P_{ij} = 1$ and set all other elements $P_{i*}$ and $P_{*j}$ to zero.

However, I'm left with the problem that there's no obvious way to renormalize the rows and columns to sum to one. It seems like there's a problem where the probability mass is "entangled" across probability distributions, and I'm not sure how to solve it.

Comment: Is there a constraint that the rows sum to 1 or the columns sum to 1?

Comment: @Sycorax Yes, because I'm treating each row and column as a probability distribution across all members of the opposing group.